# I need help proving $2-\frac{2(j+2)}{2^{j+1}}+\frac{j+1}{2^{j+1}}=2-\frac{2j+4-j-1}{2^{j+1}}$

Tags: arithmetic

This seems simple, yet I just can't figure out how the LHS equals the RHS. Why do the terms $j$ and $1$ suddenly become negative?

$$2-\frac{2(j+2)}{2^{j+1}}+\frac{j+1}{2^{j+1}}=2-\frac{2j+4-j-1}{2^{j+1}}$$

Comment: $-a+b = -(a-b)$, so there will be minus between parts of numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LHS equals the RHS actually, just note that

$$2-\frac{2(j+2)}{2^{j+1}}+\frac{j+1}{2^{j+1}}=2-\left(\frac{2(j+2)}{2^{j+1}}-\frac{j+1}{2^{j+1}}\right) = 2-\frac{2j+4-j-1}{2^{j+1}}$$

Comment: For $j = 0$ : $2 - \frac{3}{2} = 2 - \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @openspace i know, i edited the answer in the meantime, I misread the question

Comment: Thanks, this made it much clearer!

Answer (score 1):

$$2-\frac{2(j+2)}{2^{j+1}}+\frac{j+1}{2^{j+1}}=2-\frac{2j+4}{2^{j+1}} -\frac{-j-1}{2^{j+1}}= 2-\frac{2j+4-j-1}{2^{j+1}}$$